# animate's callback function (complete) executed at start?

Tags: jquery

I'm using jQuery 1.5.1 This is my code:

```
$('.cellcontent').animate({
   left: '-=190'}, {
   easing: alert('start ani'),
   duration: 5000,
   complete: alert('end ani')});
```

I get both alerts before the animation starts!? I want the complete function to start after the animation has ended. Any thoughts?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/animate

Answer (score 35):

I see two things wrong with this.

One, `easing` should be:

> A string indicating which easing
>   function to use for the transition

And `complete` should be a function.

http://api.jquery.com/animate

```
alert('start ani');
$('.cellcontent').animate({
     left: '-=190'
   },
   {
     easing: 'swing',
     duration: 5000,
     complete: function(){
        alert('end ani');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 34):

You need to pass a function to call.  Instead you are calling the function.

```
complete:  function() { alert('end ani'); }
```

Answer (score 10):

You need to pass a function to complete.

Try this:

```
$('.cellcontent').animate({
    left: '-=190'}, {
    easing: alert('start ani'),
    duration: 5000,
    complete: function() { alert('end ani') }
});
```

Since complete expects a function, it executes the code you pass to it to get a function object that it can call back to when finished.

Comment: Yes it is, but from the question the OP wanted to know when the animation started, and this will show that.

Comment: It will work, but it's still wrong.  `alert()` returns `undefined` which is passed to `easing`, that's why it works.  If you want to know when it started, just put the `alert` before the `.animate()` call.

Comment: True, it is wrong, I was just trying to answer the direct question and left that part alone.  Other people have given better answers that address both.

Answer (score 7):

Best solution is this.

```
$('.cellcontent').animate({
    left: '-=190'}, {
    easing: alert('start ani')
}, duration).promise().done(function () {
     alert('end animation');
});
```

Answer (score 5):

from the [jquery docs](http://api.jquery.com/animate/):

```
$( "#clickme" ).click(function() {
  $( "#book" ).animate({
    opacity: 0.25,
   left: "+=50",
    height: "toggle"
  }, 5000, function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

declare them in a function first, otherwise the method is called instantly:

```
var onComplete = function () {
    alert('end ani');
};
```

then call them without the ()

```
$('.cellcontent').animate({
    left: '-=190'}, {
    easing:  'slow', 
    duration: 5000,
    complete: onComplete //<-- function is passed as a variable, not called directly
 });
```

**or** wrap them directly into a function (less readable and slower when calling this a lot):

```
$('.cellcontent').animate({
  left: '-=190'}, {
  easing:  'slow',
  duration: 5000,
  complete:  function () {
        alert('end ani');
  }
});
```

Comment: easing is normally a string, in this case I have no Idea what the OP's intentions are or how he gets to this code.

Comment: @Caspar: `easing` is *always* a string.  I'm assuming the OP wants a function to be called before the animation (hence 'start ani').

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. I misunderstood easing. I understand it defines the acceleration of the animation. The default is 'swing' (parabolic) and the other option is 'lineair'.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you need "complete"?

```html
slideToggle(
     "fast","swing", function(){
       // your code here
      }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I had several elements matching the selector. And when I changed the HTML and the code to have only one element, matching the selector, then all was fine.

Answer (score -1):

```
$('.cellcontent').animate({
  left: '-=190',
  easing:  'slow',
  duration: 5000,
  function () {
    alert('end ani');
  }
});
```