# jQuery .animate callback firing at start of animation

Tags: jquery, callback, jquery-animate, hide

I have a question regarding the callback of the .animate function. I am trying to let an element fade out when the cursor leaves its parent. After fading out, the element should be hidden so you can't hover over it with the cursor or click it. However, the callback function which hides the element is called at the start of the animation instead of at the end. I've tried a lot of things but nothing worked. I can post all my code (it's not much, just a small homepage with some links I made for myself) if it's needed.

```
var fadeIn = {opacity: "1"};
var fadeOut = {opacity: "0"};

$(".link-main").hover(function(){
    $(this).children(".link-sub").css("z-index", "10").show().animate(fadeIn, 100);
}, function(){
    // The animation.
    $(this).children(".link-sub").animate(fadeOut, 100, "swing", function(){
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

Also, simply using .fadeIn and .fadeOut didn't work for whatever reason. The elements would just disappear instantly.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: this is what I have right now jsfiddle.net/rqfcZ

Comment: Did you perchance set [$.fx.off](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.fx.off/) to `true`?

Comment: Duplicate question see below stackoverflow question.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5397260/animates-callback-function-complete-executed-at-start

Comment: I've managed to do similar things by chaining together animations so each animation runs in the callback of the previous. You should just be able to use the call back on animate() instead of on hover()?

Comment: @Akash, not a duplicate, this questioner correctly passes the callback to `animate()` and does not invoke it instead.

Answer (score 2):

`.fadeIn` and `.fadeOut` does the `.show()` and `.hide()` themselves. 
Try removing them and not using animate.

Just `$(element).fadeOut()`

Also for the events, you're using old jquery syntax. Take a look at the docs for `.on()`

Comment: It's not necessary to use on() unless a person expects to be acting on dynamically-created elements. The on() method replaces live(), but not all event handlers.

Comment: @isherwood you're right. But since `.hover` is a shorthand for `.on('mouseenter mouseleave')` (as said in the docs) i think it would be better to learn only `.on` for a beginner. They deprecated other specific functions like `.click()`

Comment: @Paolo, where do you see `click()` is deprecated?

Comment: @isherwood and btw no, you were wrong. As docs says: As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method provides all functionality required for attaching event handlers

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi my fault. not yet deprecated.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I've already tried this. I just used .fadeOut(100) (without .hide) and it instantly hid the element. I've also tried using .on but it didn't work.

Comment: @WouterFlorijn hmm... please post a fiddle. everytime I used `.fadeOut()` it worked.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rqfcZ/ This is exactly what I have right now. A basic page with links. Some links have 'child' links, which should fade in when you hover over the main link and fade out when you move the cursor away. However, as you can see, they instantly disappear. When I use fadeOut, they also instantly disappear.

Comment: @WouterFlorijn it was due to the css applied (`transform`). Look at this edited and cleaned version of your example: http://jsfiddle.net/rqfcZ/1/

Answer (score 0):

@Frederic Hamidi My bad.... apologies

Please visit this link for resolution

http://fisherwebdev.com/wordpress/2009/06/08/scope-issues-with-the-callback-to-jquerys-animate-function/

A quick look on above link and came to conclusion that you need to add a ref variable to this.

Comment: I only have a basic understanding of JS/jQuery, so I don't really understand the article. Could you maybe tell me exactly what I have to change in my code?

Comment: I have edited you fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/Akash619/ZdrZW/, please have a look all I have added is ref variable to $(this) like var a=$(this); Please play along to get the functionality right as desired...