# Why animate's callback function (complete) executed at start?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Duplicate:**

Yes it is but a little bit different from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5397260/animates-callback-function-complete-executed-at-start).

I'm using jQuery 3.1.0 This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    ToggleAsideBar();
});

function ToggleAsideBar(){
$(".ah-sidebar-toggle").click(function(){
    let toggleSize = $(".ah-logo").width() == 230 ? "50px" : "230px";
    $(".ah-logo").animate(
      { width: toggleSize },200,"linear",function () {alert("Animation Complete!");'}
    );
  });
}
```

**Problem:**

In my case, alert show before the animation starts. I want to show alert after the animation completed. Any thoughts what I am doing wrong in above code?

**Live Example:**

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1n6kr20v/)

Comment: Bad link of duplicate. Please fix it.

Comment: Now you can check I fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had a collision between jquery's `animation` and css's transition.
If you decide to use `animate` - you should remove the `transition` lines from your css file.

Here is a working version (without the transition in your css):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  ToggleAsideBar();
});
function ToggleAsideBar(){
  //Get width of browser
  $(".ah-logo").click(function(){
        let toggleSize = $(".ah-logo").width() == 230 ? "50px" : "230px";
        $(".ah-logo").animate(
          { width: toggleSize },200,"swing"
        ).promise().done(function(){
            alert("Animation Complete!");
          });
  });
  
}
```

```css
.ah-logo {
  width: 230px;
    
    float: left;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    
}

a {
  line-height: 50px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<div class="ah-logo">
<a href="#">Admin</a>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "a collision"? `css` `transition` should not affect `jQuery.animate()`, `.promise()` or `.done()`

Comment: @Dekel Can you please solve another little issue. In above jsfiddle output why css show remaining effect after alert box.

Comment: Can you please be more specific? Which jsfiddle?

Comment: _"why css show remaining effect after alert box."_ Duration of `transition` is greater than `.animate()` duration

Comment: @Dekel in your above code snippet. Animation completed after alert box show.

Comment: @guest271314 I remove transition from css. But still css show remaining effect after alert box.

Comment: @AhmerAliAhsan _"I remove transition from css. But still css show remaining effect after alert box."_ Not certain how this would be possible?

Comment: @guest271314 Main problem has been resolved. When I posted this question my problem is when I clicked on div its shows me first alert box then animation start. After Dekel answer I update my code by removing css transition and code run fines. But a little issue which I faced is div successfully animate but when alert box is showed then after that a little bit animation which is left, now complete. If you still not understand then try my jsfiddle by removing css transitions.