# how to add css class when it slideUp and add css class when it slideDown?

Tags: jquery

> how to add css class when it slideUp and add css class when it slideDown?

```js
$("#hide_top").click(function () {
             $("#hide_top").addClass();
            $("#formdate").slideUp(); 
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```
 $("#hide_top").click(function () {$("#formdate")});
```

Comment: can rephrase your question or ask what you intend to achieve in particular.

Comment: $("#hide_top").click(function () {
            $("#formdate").slideToggle(); 
        });    how to add class when it slideup and when it slide down

Comment: you just copied code that you already had on the question! what are you trying to achieve? what is not working

Comment: how to slide up and down bootstrap panel

Comment: I think what your asking might be solved by this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5397260/animates-callback-function-complete-executed-at-start